# Can I use images from Google results on my website?

Tags: parsing

I'm planning to create a module for my directory which would fetch images from user's website using Google Image Search via this scenario:

1. User logs in to his account
2. Enter his website URL
3. Application request images from domain cached by google
4. Application displays N amount of images from website offering to link them to his profile
5. On confirmation, application will copy images to my server

Am I allowed to do that, and would it breach any copyrights?

**UPDATE**

I presume that person created account in my business directory is owner of that website (it states in Terms and Conditions) and as an owner he is accessing his website. Application would display thumbnails and fetch original image from his website using links from Google results. Does it make any difference?

Comment: not programming related in the least.

Comment: belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: IANAL

As long as you only use thumbnails of maximum 80 to 200 pixels in size, then it is considered [fair use](http://www.labnol.org/internet/pictures/using-thumbnails-of-copyrighted-images-is-fair-use/1882/). I also advise linking the image the source page and mentioning somewhere that the images may be copyright material.

Make sure to use the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/), rather than scraping the results page.

Comment: @Nazariy If you are using images for which you have copyright, then you have nothing to be concerned about and you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that the Google images results have this disclaimer attached to them: "This image may be subject to copyright." I'd say you'd be in the wrong.

Comment: how does it apply to person who is or pretend to be owner of copyrighted materials?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Facebook, you can use the images to link to those website. You need to mention that these images may be copyright protected. Google cache's the content. And it's image search says, "Image may be subject to copyright"

Comment: I'm planing to fetch images only from his website (which user confirmed to be an owner of this business)

Comment: then probably it's alright to pull the images and use them. Make a clause in your end user agreement saying that you can use the images and texts from their website for [place whatever purpose you are using the images... may be marketing or promotions] purposes. This will keep you safe. But consult a lawyer. We develop content management for universities, and we have similar clause. But we make sure that their IP right stays protected.